# Lucene query performance

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a lucene index which has close to 480M documents. The size of the index is 36G. And I ran around 10000 queries against the index. Each query is a boolean AND query with 3 term queries inside. That is the query has 3 operands which MUST occur. Executing such 3 word queries gives the following latency percentiles.

```
50th = 16 ms
75th = 52 ms
90th = 121 ms
95th = 262 ms
99th = 76010 ms
99.9th = 76037 ms
```

Is the latency expected to degrade when the number of docs is as high as 480M? All the segments in the index are merged into one segment. Even when the segments are not merged, the latencies are not very different. Each document has 5-6 stored fields. But as mentioned above, the above latencies are for boolean queries that don't access any stored fields, but just do a posting list lookup on 3 tokens.

Any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Comment: As usual when benchmarking stuff; show the code!